Building the theoretical foundation for generating functions - formal power series
I have read several documents on generating functions. I would like to inquire about two issues:

Among the materials I have read, some mention generating functions constructed from formal power series (an algebraic structure). In this approach, operations are developed similar to those for power series in analysis. Then, when necessary, they view generating functions as a power series (in the analytical sense) over a domain where the series converges. A few materials begin with defining generating functions as power series in analysis, over a domain where the series converges. I want to ask which approach truly constitutes the starting point for generating functions. Furthermore, why are there these two approaches? What significance do they hold? I still do not understand.

Dirichlet generating functions are also considered a type of generating function, yet they are not any form of formal power series. So, ultimately, what is a generating function and how many types are there?



I like the way of constructing from from formal power series, it provides a solid foundation for generating functions, compared to the second method. However, with that construction, I don't have a way to build Dirichlet generating functions.
My construction method is similar to the one described in the article here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1365/s13291-022-00256-6

Thank you, of course, I have seen and understood them. I am asking about how to build the theoretical foundation if starting from formal power series for Dirichlet generating functions. If starting from analysis, I have nothing to say (I reiterate, ordinary generating functions and exponential generating functions are built from formal power series, so I want to ask if that can be done for Dirichlet generating functions).
